# Is there a way to diff chown/chmod between two servers' directories?

Tags: linux, debugging, diff, chmod, chown

Platform: CentOS 5.6 x86_64

I have a production server and a development server. I want to debug file ownership and permissions across a large directory structure, which is almost identical, give or take a few ephemeral files in temporary caches.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Manually checking file-for-file would not be practical, given the size of the directory tree.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://linuxconfig.org/backup-permissions-in-linux

This is the BEST script to bakup and restore the permissions of directories. When you get the directory permissions list from both servers, just run a diff on them (you might want to make some modificatins before that)

Comment: A bit belated, but better late than never, eh? Thanks again.

Comment: Is it possible to get the timestamp of when the file was created or changed and who did it along with this command  ?

Answer (score 2):

Just use find on both directory servers with the -ls flag, like:

```
find directory_a -not ( test_for_ephemeral_files ) -ls > listing_a
find directory_b -not ( test_for_ephemeral_files ) -ls > listing_b
diff listing_a listing_b
```

Comment: `-ls` will print the file modification time and file size as well.  Instead, you should use something like `-printf '%p %M %u/%g\n'`, which will print out only the desired information.